# Any add-ons there for change blender interface into regional language?

Tags: interface, add-on

I like to teach blender for people region languages if is there any add-on for change blender in regional language. other vice witch API helps to change the interface language.If its there its very helpful to learn tech skills in regional language.

Answer (score 2):

The language option is in Preferences.

**Edit** > **Preferences** > **Interface** > **Translation**

[image]