# How do I enable the 'Language' option in the Translation drop-down Options box?

Tags: interface

On my installation of Blender 3.2.1 I click these various options:
Edit -> Preferences -> Interface -> Translation -> Language and this gives only the option Automatic: (Automatic) option which is clickable and then underneath the option labelled 'Language' which is grayed out and unclickable. Every tutorial/youtube video I have seen says I should be able to choose a language option from here. How do I enable this option? Other people seem to click on an option and another menu appears with various languages included.

I am using Linux (Red Hat Fedora) as my OS.

This question does not help either, as it pretty much leads to the unsuccessful process outlined above: [Any add-ons there for change blender interface into regional language?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201069/any-add-ons-there-for-change-blender-interface-into-regional-language)

Comment: The language drop down should show you all options. Perhaps you have installed an add-on that causes issues? I would recommend that you check if renaming `~/.config/blender/3.2/` or starting Blender with `--factory-startup`, so that Blender does not load your current preferences, resolves the issue.

Comment: No, just tried that, and although the dropdown now appears with a blank entry as the 'default' option, when I click it, I have the same choices - Automatic, or the grayed-out 'Language'. Could it be something to do with Linux Fedora?

Comment: Are you using an official build? If not I would recommend you check if the official builds work properly and in general update to 3.2.2. Also check if Blender prints any error messages to the terminal.

Comment: I think I installed it form the command line with yum install dnf blender o something. Is there a way of 'updating' to a stock build? This version was possibly a tweaked Fedora repo version or something like that.

Comment: You can download the official Blender builds and extract them anywhere you like. Just open a terminal in the respective directory and run `./blender`.  All past releases can be found here: https://download.blender.org/release
The current version can be found here: https://www.blender.org/download/
Experimental/daily builds can be found here: https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/